# Bi-directional communication between a client page and a service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox, preact

Having a preact app generated by preact-cli (uses workbox), my objective is to register a 'message' event handler on the service worker, post a message from the app and finally receive a response back.

Something like:

```
/* app.js */
navigator.serviceWorker.postMessage('marco');

const response = ? // get the response somehow
```

```js
/* sw.js */
addEventListener('message', function (e) { return 'polo' });
```

I don't have much experience with service workers and there are a lot of moving parts that confuse me, like workbox doing magic on service worker, preact hiding away the code that registers the sercice worker and service workers being tricky to debug in general.

So far I've placed a `sw.js` file in the `src/` directory as instructed by the preact-cli docs here: https://preactjs.com/cli/service-worker/

I know I am supposed to attach an event listener but I can't find documentation on which object to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Neither Workbox nor Preact have much to do with this question. Workbox allows you to use any additional code in your service worker that you'd like, and Preact should as well for your client app.)

[This example page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/) demonstrates sending a message from a client page to a service worker and then responding, using [`MessageChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel). The relevant helper code used on the client page looks like:

```
function sendMessage(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
    messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function(event) {
      // The response from the service worker is in event.data
      if (event.data.error) {
        reject(event.data.error);
      } else {
        resolve(event.data);
      }
    };

    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(message,
      [messageChannel.port2]);
  });
}
```

And then in your service worker, you used the `MessageChannel`'s port to respond:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // Your code here.

  event.ports[0].postMessage({
    error: // Set error if you want to indicate a failure.
    message: // This will show up as event.data.message.
  });
});
```

You could also do the same thing using the [Comlink library](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink/issues/27#issuecomment-397675428) to simplify the logic.